# Searching for specific values in Splunk query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

In this following query

```
index=sne host=nwbsnep* sourcetype=sne_CAS_elilogs OR sourcetype=sne_CMS_elilogs "Service.Operation"="*"
```

Service Operation fetches 36 values out of which I need specific 7.

For this, I wrote another query

```
index=sne host=nwbsnep* (sourcetype=sne_CAS_elilogs OR sourcetype=sne_CMS_elilogs) ("Service.Operation"="A" OR "Service.Operation"="B" OR "Service.Operation"="C" OR "Service.Operation"="D "OR "Service.Operation"="E" OR "Service.Operation"="F" OR "Service.Operation"="G" OR "Service.Operation"="H")
```

This query is returning events of only `Service.Operation=F` and not of all the 7 events. Is there some mistake I am making with boolean expressions?

Comment: Your search expression appears correct, can you provide some sample data so we can determine why this isn't working as intended?

Comment: what up with the "(" around source type and search value? Any particular reasons? Also, you don't need to "Service. Operation" all the time, just rename it and put the single name and use without " "

Comment: @parlad - parentheses make the search explicit

Comment: @parlad - you cannot rename a field in the first line of a SPL search. Unless you can alias it in props.conf, Joey's done the right thing

Answer (score 0):

For readibility, try using [`IN()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Search#4._Using_the_IN_operator):

```
index=sne host=nwbsnep* sourcetype IN(sne_CAS_elilogs,sne_CMS_elilogs) Service.Operation IN("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
```

The issue *seems* to have been, though, that in your second parenthesized set of `OR`s, you had this:

```
OR "Service.Operation"="D "OR "Service.Operation"="E" OR "Service.Operation"="F"
```

In SPL, the `OR` has to be separated from what it's or'ing by at least one space

You had one slammed against a quote mark